# Assuming GCC and G++ are installed how to compile a file which uses boost library? (threading)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

So I am new to linux stuff. I have set linux Debian up, I have gcc installed. I have a simple C++ file that uses boost threading library. Let us call that file example.cpp we have exect path to it. how to compile it? (sorry I came from windows world=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `example.cpp` is in the current directory, this will create an executable called `example`, linked against `boost-thread`. `g++` will search the system library locations for the library.

`g++ example.cpp -lboost-thread -o example`

Comment: will it download boost for me if it is not installed?

Comment: oh, no I'm assuming boost-thread is installed: to install boost libraries you want to do something like `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`